# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

I'm new to JavaEE and currently learning JavaEE7.  I have JavaEE7 installed and downloaded NetBeans 8.0.2 so I could follow allow with the Webinar published here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCNslREYpD0&spfreload=10

This tutorial in the video uses JavaEE6 rather than JavaEE7.

I made it about 12 minutes into the Webinar before I encountered the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` mentioned in the title of my post.  At [12:18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCNslREYpD0#t=738) in the video, the presenter adds a `@PersistenceUnit` to the code, and then an `EntityManagerFactory`.  Even though I have followed his tutorial very carefully, I'm having issues with persistence and keep getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.getDelegate(EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.java:103)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.java:114)
at org.glasssfish.samples.TestServlet.processRequest(TestServlet.java:79)
at org.glasssfish.samples.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:103)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have search StackOverflow and Google extensively, and the answer I keep coming across relates to the location of the `persistence.xml` file.  I'm using NetBeans which automatically creates and places the `persistence.xml` file in a `Configuration Files` folder.

The project layout in NetBean 8.0.2 looks like the following:

```
Web Pages
    WEB-INF
    index.html
Source Packages
    org.glassfish.samples
        TestServlet.java
    org.glassfish.samples.model
        Friend.java
Libraries
    JDK 1.8 (Default)
    GlassFish Server 4.1
Configuration Files
    MANIFEST.MF
    persistence.xml
```

Here is `Friend.java` file that was automatically generated by NetBeans as part of the tutorial:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.glasssfish.samples.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "FRIEND")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Friend.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Friend f"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Friend.findByName", query = "SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Friend.findByAge", query = "SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.age = :age")})
public class Friend implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Integer age;

    public Friend() {
    }

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Friend)) {
            return false;
        }
        Friend other = (Friend) object;
        if ((this.name == null && other.name != null) || (this.name != null && !this.name.equals(other.name))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "org.glasssfish.samples.model.Friend[ name=" + name + " ]";
    }

}
```

Here is the `TestServlet.java` file:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.glasssfish.samples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.glasssfish.samples.model.Friend;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceUnit  
    EntityManagerFactory emf;


    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet TestServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet TestServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");


            // 
            int count;
            if (request.getSession().getAttribute("count") == null) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                count = (Integer)request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("count", ++count);
            out.println("Accessed again: " + request.getSession().getAttribute("count"));


            Friend f = (Friend)emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Friend.findAll").getResultList().get(0);
            out.println("Friend name: " + f.getName());


            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

And, of course, the seemingly infamous `persistence.xml` file that was automatically generated by NetBean 8.0.2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="JavaEE7WebinarPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I tried a variety of things like:

- injecting a `PersistenceContext` instead of a `PersistenceUnit` and getting an `EntityManager` directly from there instead of using an `EntityManagerFactor` (not sure if I did that correctly).
- modifying my `@PersistenceUnit` to `@PersistenceUnit(unitName="JavaEE7WebinarPU")`. This didn't help much.  It just changed my error from:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null`

to

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName JavaEE7WebinarPU`

- I verified that my GlassFish server does, in fact, have a resource named `jdbc/sample` which is mapped to a pool named `SamplePool`.  I also verified that my GlassFish server has a Connection pool named `SamplePool`.  It is currently set as a `javax.sql.DataSource` resource type.

I was hoping someone with some more experience with JavaEE might be able to point out something obvious that I'm missing here.  Or maybe something that has changed from JavaEE6 to JavaEE7 which may be the cause of my error.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

/
**UPDATE:** I just ran a `Clean and Build` in NetBeans and saw the following warning:
/

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'`
```

I have JDK 1.8 installed (update 31), NetBeans 8.0.2, and GlassFish 4.1. Is this warning suggesting that eclipseLink won't work with JDK 1.8?

/
**UPDATE #2:** Ok, well this seems to be a very lame resolution.  After trying to fix this for a couple of hours. I shut down my GlassFish server, Disconnected from my database, performed a 'Clean and Build', started everything back up again, and redeployed.  Now everything seems to be working as I expect it to.  I suppose something got a little wonky somewhere and only a 'clean' was able to resolve the issue. Ugh.
/

Comment: what is the location of your persistence.xml. It should be on myapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml.

Comment: shikjohari, it is located in the location that you suggest.  I have not had to manipulate the location of the persistence.xml file.  NetBeans 8.0.2 seems to be managing that file completely.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently something in my build got a little funky.  I shut down all my servers, did a **Clean and Build** and redeployed.  Now, everything seems to be working.

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks I had same problem with payara, this fixed it. I think after adding a new datasource to the server it is possibly not available to be injected into applications until the server has been restarted.

Answer (score 0):

What I found missing in your persistence.xml is the provider. In your persistence-unit element add the following tag also

```
<provider> provider_name</provider>
```

check which provider you are using

Comment: I didn't specify a provider in my persistence.xml file.  It was auto-generated by NetBean 8.0.2.  However, the IDE indicates that it will use EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) as the provider if no other provider is specified.

Comment: I just attempted to change the provider to Hibernate.  When I select hibernate, NetBeans adds a provider line to my persistence.xml file that looks like the following:

`<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`

However, I still get the same error.

Comment: ok, I also just attempted to specify EclipseLink as my provider:

`<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>`

it also produces the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have specified entity manager in your post and you trying to access entity manager both are different please see
You  should do like this

```
 @PersistenceContext(name="entiyManager")
 EntityManager entitymanager;
```

Also you need to initialized your entitymanager factory

Comment: himanshu, thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried:

    `@PersistenceContext(name="em", unitName="JavaEE7WebinarPU")
    EntityManager em;`

as well as:

    `@PersistenceUnit(name="emf", unitName="JavaEE7WebinarPU")
    EntityManager emf;`

They both give me the same error when trying to access either em or emf respectively:

    `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: Sorry, small typo in my previous comment.  I tried

`@PersistenceUnit(name="emf", unitName="JavaEE7WebinarPU") EntityManagerFactory emf;`

My edit time expired.

Comment: Have you declare entity manager factory bean anywhere ? You need to do that .Which framework you using ? If not then looks for spring , it is most used and easy framework ,than integrate it with Jpa.

Answer (score 0):

James, I think it is a simple solution. 
change from

```
@PersistenceUnit
```

to

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="JavaEE7WebinarPU")
```

also see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUnit.html

Answer (score 0):

No problem buddy its very easy just add this in persistence.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="JavaEE7WebinarPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You have an option at persistence class generated by netbeans to name your persistence unit. After naming it just do a clean and build and you will get your answer.